# JavaScript error: property is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm a Java programmer experimenting with JavaScript objects. I get an error for this code:

```
var a = {
    map: new Map(),
    put: function (k, v) {
        map.set(k, v);
    }
}
a.put("key", "value");
```

Error is: Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With literal objects you are not able to access the keys directly at definition time because they do not yet exist. You need to use execution of the function combined with the this keyword to refer to own properties

```
var a = {
    map: new Map(),
    put: function (k, v) {
        this.map.set(k, v);
    }
}
a.put("key", "value");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use object name (`a`) or `this` to refer the property like:

```
a.map.set(k, v);
```

**OR:**

```
this.map.set(k, v);
```

```js
var a = {
    map: new Map(),
    put: function (k, v) {
        this.map.set(k, v);
    }
}
a.put("key", "value");
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, welcome to the dark side. To answer your question, you have to reference the `map` key in your object declared as `a` as `a.map`. So like this.

```
var a = {
    map: new Map(),
    put: function (k, v) {
        a.map.set(k, v);
    }
}
a.put("key", "value");
```